# Databinding in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

Is it possible to do data binding on the fields of an object just like in WPF?

Something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=lbColor}" />
```

just for an asp:TextBox element. What I want is that on submit to have the new values inside the binded object and I don't want to manually read and set the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are binding in a template you can use:

```
<asp:textbox Text="<%#Bind("lbColor")%>" runat="server" />
```

see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not binding in a template. Is there any other solution?

Comment: you can use the FormView a quick databindable control, put your controls into the <ItemTemplate>, set it's datasource to your object and then run databind()

Answer (score 0):

For those looking, I made this javascript plugin.  It does data binding very close to what WPF does and is easy to use.  It has attached documentation in a .txt file

https://github.com/jdemeuse1204/ObjectDataBinding

Here is an example of what one of my bindings looks like

```
<input runat="server" style="width: 50px;" data-bind="path: Quote" />
```

To activate you call

```
$("#yourelementname").observe(yourobject, 'yourbindingname');
```

To get the object back for saving or other operations

```
var obj= $("#yourelementname").getObserveObject('yourbindingname');
```